# this C++ code always gives same output

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Here is a program that checks whether a number and its reverse are equal

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int num,n,digit,j,newNum;
 n=num;
 j=1;
 newNum=0;

cout<<"Enter a number\n";
cin>>num;

while(n>=1)
{
   digit=n%10;
n=n/10;
digit=digit*j;
newNum=newNum+digit;
j=j*10;        
}
  cout<<"The reverse of given number is:"<<newNum<<endl;
  if(num==newNum)
  cout<<"The given number and its reverse are equal";
  else
  cout<<"The given number and its reverse are not equal";
  getch();   
}
```

`
This program accept a number as input and then find its reverse and then check if reverse is equal to number or not.
        whenever I run this program and whatever number I give as input, it gives the reverse number 1975492148.
        Can anyone please help me with identifying the cause of it?

Comment: your `n` variable is not initialized, move `n=num` after you read from cin

Comment: thank you so much.It was such a silly mistake.

Comment: Your steps in your while loop don't look like any algorithm I've ever seen to "reverse a number" (Do you mean than an input of '96' should give an output of '69'?) - have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: btw. the reverse would be easier when you handle the input as a string

Comment: I have dry run it now and yes you are right it does not give the desired output.It gives the input number back.To make it work I need to know how to calculate no of digits in a number and then I can modify my algorithm and make it work.

Comment: actually I am a student and it was a homework.we have not studied strings so far so I have to do it with simple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int num;
  cout<<"Enter a number\n";
  cin>>num;

  int n = num;
  int rev = 0;
  while( n >= 1 )
  {
    int rem = n%10; 
    rev = (rev*10) + rem;
    n=n/10;
  }


  cout<<"The reverse of given number is:"<<rev<<endl;

  if(num==rev)
    cout<<"The given number and its reverse are equal" << endl;
  else
    cout<<"The given number and its reverse are not equal" << endl;
  getch();   
}
```

Comment: wonderful,very mpressive.thank you so much.I was working on it but I dont think that I would have done it in only three lines.

Comment: @farheen Glad to help you. Please accept it as an answer. Advise : Do some paper work while you are doing your assignments or learning and then coding will be lot easier. Or just debug your program stepwise.

Comment: I will.I truly appreciate your advice.

Comment: btw have you done it before or you did it on the spot?I am very much impressed.I really want to become a very good programmer.I guess my problem solving skill is not that bad.How can I become a smart programmer?

Comment: It's a neat solution (plus one), but the loop @SmartDev is using is very idiomatic. All comes with experience.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of the assignment `n=num;` is *undefined*. This is because `num` has not been initialised at this point.

You then make further use of `n` later in the program, as your `while` condition. This will not end well.